# Thyme leaf fail to parse when there is backbone template in html

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, thymeleaf

Thyme leaf fail to parse a html file, within i want to use a template for backbonejs view and give the following error message:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of
>   well-formed character data or markup.

The html code that cause the problem:

```
    <!-- models -->
<script type="text/template" id="template_slider">

  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title"><%= panel_title %></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <input id="<%= id %>" data-slider-id="<%= slider_id %>" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="0.01" data-slider-value="0" />
    </div>
  </div>

</script>
```

The solution for the problem is easy, just have to use `/*<![CDATA[*/` with the matching end tag `/*]]>*/` but with this the backbone fail and when i want to create the new view throw the following error message

> Uncaught ReferenceError: panel_title is not defined(anonymous function) @ VM2747:6template @ underscore.js:1461access @ jquery.js:3626jQuery.fn.extend.html @ jquery.js:5486Backbone.View.extend.render @ map.Control.js:92Backbone.View.extend.initialize @ map.Control.js:83Backbone.View @ backbone.js:1224child @ backbone.js:1884(anonymous function) @ map.Control.js:96o.Mixin.Events.fireEvent @ leaflet.js:6o.Path.o.Path.extend._fireMouseEvent @ leaflet.js:7o.Path.o.Path.extend._onMouseClick @ leaflet.js:7t.(anonymous function).s @ leaflet.js:8

There is the js script in question:

```
 polyline.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var SliderView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function() {
        this.render();
      },
      render : function(){
        var variables = {
          panel_title : "Random",
          id : "my_id",
          slider_id : "my_idSlider"
        };
        var template = _.template( $("#template_slider").html(), variables );
        this.$el.html(template);
      }
    });

    var slider_view = new SliderView({ el: $("#slider_container")});
  });
```

I tried it offline without spring and thymeleaf the js code works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure Thymaleaf to parse in HTML5Legacy mode.

Since I do not know, how you are using thymaleaf, I cannot provide you a working code.

You usualy do this in a config file or by injecting a view configurer and do it there...

Comment: Thx, it's work! 
I use spring with thymeleaf, the most simple to put the following line `spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5` into  `application.properties`